# create two list from one in python?

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and I want to make two different list from a list.
e.g.

```
  main list ,list=[[1,2],[3,4,],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]

  derived list, list1=[[1,2],[3,4,],[5,6]],list2=[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
```

What is the way do so.
I Even try :

```
import numpy as np

list1=list2=[]

list=[[1,2],[3,4,],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]

for x in range(0,5):

    if x<=2:

        list1=np.append(list1,list[x])

    else:

        list2=np.append(list2,list[x])

print list1,list2



# output: [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.] [  7.   8.   9.  10.]
```

Comment: Why are you using `numpy` here??

Comment: Also, heads up, this: `list1=list2=[]` does *not create two separate lists*. It assigns the *same list* to *two different names*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, I have only used if-else to make it simple.

```
l = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
p = [1,0,0,1,0,1]

l1 = []
l2 = []

for i in range(0, len(l)):
    if p[i] == 0:
        l1.append(l[i])
    else:
        l2.append(l[i])

print(l1)
print(l2)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 10]]
[[1, 2], [7, 8], [11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
l =[[1,2],[3,4,],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]

l1 = l[:len(l)//2]

l2 = l[len(l)//2:]

print l1
print l2
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to know more generalized way. Through which even I create list like: l3=[[3,4][7,8][9,10]].

Comment: Please specify the various parameters that you would like the lists to be broken up into. In the example in your question, you want an list of an even length to be broken in half, which is what this code accomplishes. However, what do you want to have happen if the code is of uneven length?

Comment: Ok. I take a parameter  cp=[0,1,1,0,0,1].If cp's element is '0' than 'list' element is copied in 'list1' and if cp's element is '1' than it should copied in 'list2'

Comment: There are multiple elements in cp. Which ones do you choose?

Comment: Accessing each of its element with the for loop.